# avoid cross site scripting via httpmodules for use in asp.net mvc2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, csrf

Is there a better way other than the `Anti Forgery Token` like built-in functionalities in asp.net mvc2. I would like to code my own http module to avoid CSRF.

Also to my understanding the Antiforgerytoken does not generate any cookies. Is the `"double-submitted cookie"` a good method?

Any best practices or suggestions.

--edit :
This link is useful: [Stackoverflow previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I need some of the other better ways that can evade cookie stealing and other formats. I also donot use captcha, a better alternative though.. I want to handle this issue from the IIS levels...

Comment: Maybe explain why you need to handle it at the IIS level. I say that because using the AntiForgeryToken would be considered the best practice. And yes, it does produce a cookie... that's how it all works. This blog post has a good explaination on how it all works. http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/

Comment: @Charlino: Basically my solution will be a library and that has to take care of avoiding CSRF. I will have no UI and want the user of my library to forget about CSRF as i handle it from my library. I have too tested antiforgerytoken and works fine, but am in need of a serverside solution.

Comment: The OWASP CSRFGuard for .NET would be worth a look. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.Net_CSRF_Guard

Answer (score 1):

This library looks similar to what you are writing. http://anticsrf.codeplex.com/
It uses a cookie for a token. I've used it and it helped my project pass a security review.