# XSS vulnerabilities occur, how to solve this?

Tags: asp.net, security, xss

I got security issue in our application. I am not understanding below question, Please any one let me know, what it is and how to solve this generic issue? How to scan website with security related tools?

Thread – XSS vulnerabilities occur when the Web application echoes user-supplied data in an HTML response sent to the Web browser. For example, a Web application might include the user's name as part of a welcome message or display a home address when confirming a shipping destination. If the user-supplied data contain characters that are interpreted as part of an HTML element instead of literal text, then an attacker can modify the HTML that is received by the victim's Web browser.

Ex: http://mydomain/Products.aspx?category=%22%20onEvent%3dX151232644Y1Z%20&name=Healthcare

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you avoid XSS vulnerabilities in ASP.Net (MVC)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: i am using dotnet framework 3.5 . i think these may not be useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWASP goes into some great detail on the subject in their "[XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)".

Comment: A simple XSS attack might involve a person e-mailing a link to your site with some parameters that exploit an XSS vulnerability allowing JavaScript and/or HTML they supply to be injected into the presented page.  It looks to the user like it came from you, but may include visuals, code, or instructions introduced by the attacker.

Comment: There are a number of tools and online services that scan for XSS.  Most of them spider your website and try posting form data crafted to try to "inject" javascript or tags that they can detect in the page.  Examples include qualys.com (good support for regulatory compliance) or tenable.com (good for broad-spectrum of different types of vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AntiXSS in your web application.

**Tutorials**

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814

**Useful tools**

*Microsoft Web Protection Library* http://wpl.codeplex.com/

**Exploit XSS**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx

http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html

**Basic way to prevent XSS**

Input --> Anti-SQL Injection --> Store in DB --> Anti-XSS --> Output

Comment: these links related to dotnet 4.0 framework. we are using 3.5, can u explain how to scan website in terms of vulnerability.

Comment: I've updated my post. Let's read and understand simple xss bug. You will find the way to prevent it.