# security of MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security, xss

I am currently working on an Asp.Net MVC3 project for a front end eCommerce site. I am doing some research in to security of the controller actions, in particular XSS etc. Could anyone point me to some relevant articles and/or blog posts that would assist me with securing my application?

Comment: Did you google it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc  and http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this article to be nice in concerning XSS in understanding XSS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708755.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [MVC Security Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security) from ASP.net/MVC

This is a FREE video from Pluralsight that covers MVC3 security including XSS, Windows Authentication, Forms Authentication, and the ASP.net Membership Provider. [MVC3 Security](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro)

Here are some additional links on the topic:

[Securing your MVC3 Application by Rick Anderson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx)

[MVC Security with Haack and Hanselman](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/FT05)