# Does ASP.NET MVC 4 require extra XSS handling by default

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, xss

ASP.NET MVC 4 by default ignores HTML input in a post message. If I don't explicitly accept HTML, is there any code I need to write to defend my site against XSS attacks? I won't be using `[AllowHtml]` or `[ValidateInput(false)]`. I'm just trying to find out if I should worry about XSS attacks or not. I'm using Razor as my view engine.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: That's mentioning ASPX syntax. I'm using Razor. Also, I'm using the latest version of MVC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found an excellent blog post by [Amir Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769831/amir-ismail) that addresses all of your concerns. http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.com/2012/03/save-aspnet-mvc-application-against.html

To summarize what he writes.
Razor is encoded default unless `Html.Raw` is used.
`Html.AntiForgeryToken()` can be used to create a random token that will protect against CSRF however it requires the user to accept cookies.

Comment: The provided link is broken!