# MVC4/5 - what XSS vulnerabilities must I explicitly guard against?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xss

I know that MVC by default has a level of protection against XSS. The backend code catches suspicious javascript in a submitted form, and Razor will HTML-encode output with it's @Html helpers.

I believe these two features protect me from XSS be it from the user entering javascript into a form submission, or if some script has been written to the database and I am outputting it to the page via a @Html helper (with the exception of @Html.Raw()).

Are there any XSS techniques I need to guard against with the latest versions of MVC?

I have read the [OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)  but I think MVC covers all bases.

The only vulnerability I can think of is if script gets written into the database and I load that data into my page via JQuery, but that is not an MVC problem.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about XSS vulnerabilities as `Razor` engine will take care of most of the things.

Comment: The main thing people do by mistake is try to use user input from within a <script> context.  make sure that you are not emitting any user input in there and you should be fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ASP.NET MVC 4 require extra XSS handling by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691958/does-asp-net-mvc-4-require-extra-xss-handling-by-default)