# how to solve Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

While using

return Json(educationModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Where educationModel is the object of the controller which iam using.

But I am getting an security issue shown below.

"The method sends unvalidated data to a web browser ,which can result in the browser executing malicious code".

I understand it is because of "Cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities".

I am using MVC 3.0 with Framework 4.0.

Can any one give me the solution for this?How to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using ValidateAntiForgeryToken ?

Comment: No i didn't , can you please elaborate or share the code snippet please?

Comment: @karthik ValidateANtiForgeryToken is for CSRF attacks. for XSS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972969.aspx#securitybarriers_topic6
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Can any one help me out?

Comment: @Ravi yes you are correct

Comment: @user2223819 here is the [Magazine from msdn on AntiXSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708755.aspx) and a blog post from [JGalloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/using-antixss-4-1-beta-as-the-default-encoder-in-asp-net.aspx)

Comment: any help . Please give me some solutions.