# XSS prevention techniques in MVC dot Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

Can anybody list down the techniques and security measures for XSS prevention in MVC dot net?

Comment: You may use AntiXSSEncoder : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: refer this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/preventing-xss-in-aspnet--cms-21801

Answer (score 0):

In our project we prevent XSS from client side it self by overriding jQuery's `.val()` function, so the idea behind this is to whenever we get the value from textbox we always get it in encoded by using following overridden function:

```js
var shouldBeEncoded = true;
//Overriding val() function of jQuery
(function ($) {
  var originalVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function() {
      if(shouldBeEncoded)
       {
         //using .text() function of jQuery to encode textas it's xss safe
         return $("<div/>").text(this[0].value).html();
        }
      else
      {
        return this[0].value;
      }
    };
})(jQuery);

$("#btnEnc").click(function(){
  shouldBeEncoded = true;
 $("#withEncoding").html("Encoded : " + $("#txt").val());
});

$("#btnNoEnc").click(function(){
  shouldBeEncoded = false;
  console.log($("#txt").val());
  $("#withtouEncoding").html("Without Encoded : " + $("#txt").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" value="<script>alert(1)</script>" />
<input type="button" value="Show me with encoding" id="btnEnc" />
<input type="button" value="Show me without encoding" id="btnNoEnc" />


<div id="withEncoding"></div>

<div id="withtouEncoding"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc) 
Is also a good idea to validate your site with tools like [AsafaWeb](https://asafaweb.com), not just for XSS but for a wider range of issues.